# App keep crashing since i added my ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-layout

*Title said everything*

Here the activity_main.xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/menuslide" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:flipInterval="3000"
    android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_right"
    android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_out_left">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/vp_1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ImageTitle"
            android:text="@string/yaounde"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/vp_2"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ImageTitle"
            android:text="@string/yaounde"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/vp_3"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ImageTitle"
            android:text="@string/yaounde"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/vp_4"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/ImageTitle"
            android:text="@string/yaounde"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</ViewFlipper>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/flipper1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="local"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="Track"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="miseenmarche"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="Activation"
        android:id="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="config"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="Configuration"
        android:id="@+id/button7" />
</TableRow>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableRow">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/facebook_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:id="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/tutoriel_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/faq_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/button10" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text=""
        android:background="@drawable/contact_icon"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/button11" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
  public Boolean active = false;
private Context context = this;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper1);

    flipper.startFlipping();

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

slide_in_right.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
   <translate
       android:fromXDelta="100%p"
       android:toXDelta="0"
       android:duration="5000"/>
</set>
```

slide_in_left.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >
   <translate
       android:fromXDelta="0"
       android:toXDelta="-100%p"
       android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

It looks all perfect but my apps keep crashing when i start the apps...If anyone can help me with this

**Update**

```
02-27 22:37:36.448  12168-12168/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.acer.thewatcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
02-27 22:37:36.483  12168-12168/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.acer.thewatcher, PID: 12168
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.acer.thewatcher/com.acer.thewatcher.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.acer.thewatcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.acer.thewatcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:694)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:519)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3382)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3715)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:926)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.acer.thewatcher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please add the stack trace you find in logcat for this crash.

Comment: when you run the app in (normal) debug mode connected to your pc, you will still have the logcat in the console. Your screenshot is worthless. The logcat tells you clearly the reason where the app is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The out of memory exception would assume you are loading too large or too many images in your Activity. Try to reduce them and supply appropriate sizes only.

The XML-inflate error might be caused by this, but can be checked only after you fixed the first. Anyway your XML-Layout is incomplete. The RelativeLayout is never closed, but maybe you just missed to copy that part.

Comment: Fixed...Trying to finish a work and didn't look for the obvious thing memory...You were right the images were to large about 1800px LOL...thanks

Comment: Re read my code about the "The RelativeLayout is never closed" ... they're all closed...